# display array of images using getelementbyid in js

Tags: javascript

```
for (i=0;i<tar.length;i++) {
document.write("<img src=" + tar[i] + " width='100' height='100'>"+"  ");
}
```

tar array has image sources, i want to display that using getElementById not by document.write

Comment: This might help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

Answer (score 0):

Using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild), you might do:

```
var myContainer = document.getElementById("someContainerId");

for (i=0;i<tar.length;i++) {
    var myimg = document.createElement("img");
    myimg.src= tar[i];
    myimg.width="100";
    myimg.height="100";

    myContainer.appendChild(myimg);
}
```

Make sure, of course, that there really is a container element with the id of `someContainerId`, or whatever id you want to give it. It might be best if the container element were a `<div>`.

Comment: i got an error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: @user1553487 The error is either because you don't have `<div id="someContainerId"></div>` in your HTML, or because you're not [waiting to the DOM to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null/11163147#11163147).

Comment: The DOM is the object model of the HTML of your page. **JavaScript code can run before the DOM is ready for use**, so `getElementById` will not work unless it runs after the DOM is loaded. As suggested in the [answer I linked previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null/11163147#11163147), either put your code in a `window.onload` handler, or place your `<script>` tag as the last element in your `<body>` tag.

Comment: i did all the options as you told but its still ends in an error. Plss clear me.

Comment: In general on Stack Overflow, you should be *showing* code rather than *asking* for code. Edit your question to include your current code and people can try to diagnose what is wrong with it.

Comment: I ve lot of functions in my program , i want to refresh and call a particular function when a button is clicked. pls answer me