# Chrome extension options page 'addEventListener' bug

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an options page for my chrome extension. I've followed this tutorial exactly: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html

Now it doesn't do anything when pressing the 'save' button. I inspected the code and it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` 
at the line: `document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', save_options);`

Comment: Are you sure you've included the `<script>` *below* the rest of your HTML? The fact that `document.querySelector('#save')` is `null` suggests to me that your script is running before the HTML is parsed.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'd put the script in its head.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set property InnerHTML of null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null) -- the situation is slightly different, but the solution is identical.

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem and thanks for @apsillers's comment by which I have solved my problem.

In the Chrome Extension tutorial, the JavaScript `<script>` tag is placed in `<head>`, which results in this `TypeError`.

**Solution**

Move the `<script>` in `<head>` tag to `<body>`.

**Example:**

**change**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
  </body>
</html>
```

**to**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <img id="image-result" hidden>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```