# How to set a specific starting volume for <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, volume

I only have basic knowledge of HTML and CSS and have looked through Google extensively trying to find an answer to this question -- it all seems to point to JavaScript and/or jQuery. I tried it, and I can't get it to work.

I have an audio file that starts to play when my website loads. I want to set a specific starting volume so that my visitors don't get a heart attack if their volume is high.

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<audio id="bgAudio" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop="loop" src="audio/025.mp3"></audio>
```

CSS:

```
#bgAudio {
position:fixed;
z-index:1000; 
width:250px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
backgroundAudio=document.getElementById("bgAudio");
backgroundAudio.volume=0.5;
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code looks fine; the problem is not in the code you've posted here. Are you sure that the `document.getElementById("bgAudio")` line runs after the DOM is constructed (e.g., inside of a `document.ready` callback or in a `<script>` tag placed at the bottom of the `<body>`)? If not, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null/11163147#11163147). Note also that iOS does not allow for programmatic alteration of volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not getting the element, and the error shows up in the console

> Cannot set property 'volume' of null

Move the script to right before the `</body>` tag, or do :

```
window.onload = function() {
    var backgroundAudio=document.getElementById("bgAudio");
    backgroundAudio.volume=0.5;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Nothing is more annoying than disabling right clicks, but anyway, here's what you have

```
;(function($){
mySong=document.getElementById("bgAudio");
mySong.volume=0.2;

setVolume = function(bgAudio,vol) {
    sounds[bgAudio].volume = 0.33;
}
})(jQuery);
```

now change it to

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#bgAudio").prop("volume", 0.2);

    window.setVolume = function(bgAudio, vol) {
        sounds[bgAudio].volume = vol;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript to set the volume, however you need to make sure to have the DOM ready to modify any objects. Perhaps use an ondocumentready event, or a Click event from a call-to-action.

First, get the video object you want to modify.

`bgAudio = document.getElementById("bgAudio");`

Then use the bgAudio object to set its properties, like the volume.

`bgAudio.volume = 0.2;`

Since you are working on a website, I would do something like this (assuming you can use jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // the site has now loaded, grab the video!
    bgAudio = document.getElementById("bgAudio");
    // now tweak the volume!
    bgAudio.volume = 0.2;
    // now, play it!
    bgAudio.play();
});
```

Check out this reference material on jquery ready, events and videos:

- http://api.jquery.com/ready/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video