# Setting volume of javascript audio

Tags: javascript, audio

So i have created audio with javascript like this:

```
var sound1 = new Audio("audio.mp3");
```

Now I want to set the volume of the audio, I have tried:

```
sound1.volume(0.5);
```

yes, i know its probably something to do with the syntax but I can't find any info on how to do this anywhere

Comment: see [How to set a specific starting volume for <audio> tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618737/how-to-set-a-specific-starting-volume-for-audio-tag)

Comment: sound1.volume=0.5;