# Basic Typescript Web App

Tags: html, typescript, dom

I am trying to pass a typescript variable to a html page.

All the code is on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/basicTypescriptWebApp) and running on [gh-pages](https://shanegibney.github.io/basicTypescriptWebApp/).

I am following a short example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) on [Typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org)

This should allow me to put a typescript variable into a DOM but it isn't working.

```
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

let user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

If this isn't possible it is possible to put a template variable in the DOM? Such as might be done with Angular2+,

```
{{ variable }}
```

The actual error I get it,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at app.ts:71
(anonymous) @ app.ts:71
```

Which possibly means I am running the code before the DOM is constructed.

Comment: Trying to get a variable from the app.ts file to show in the html after compiling to app.js

Comment: The error I get is 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at app.ts:71
(anonymous) @ app.ts:71

Comment: why should someone downvote this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Using window.onload I can load the DOM first and then call the js code,

app.ts

```
window.onload = function() {
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}

let user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
}
```

I was trying to do something simple like this,

```
window.onload = function() {

let user: string = "Jane";
let sentence: string = `${user} is super
totally cool!`;

document.body.innerHTML = "<p><strong>" + sentence + "</strong></p>";
}
```