# How to Fix JavaScript HTML Element Did Not Show an Error?

Tags: javascript, html

TypeScript code is as follows:

**namespacesLab.ts:**

```
var ArrayUtilities;
(function (ArrayUtilities) {
    function reverseArray(array) {
        return array.slice(0).reverse();
    }
    ArrayUtilities.reverseArray = reverseArray;
    function lastItemOfArray(array) {
        return array.slice(0).pop();
    }
    ArrayUtilities.lastItemOfArray = lastItemOfArray;
    function firstItemOfArray(array) {
        return array.slice(0).shift();
    }
    ArrayUtilities.firstItemOfArray = firstItemOfArray;
    function concatenateArray(array1, array2) {
        return array1.concat(array2);
    }
    ArrayUtilities.concatenateArray = concatenateArray;
})(ArrayUtilities || (ArrayUtilities = {}));
```

HTML code is as follows:

**index.html:**

```
<script src="namespacesLab.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      array2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

      function callArrayUtil(util, array, array2 = null) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = ArrayUtilities[util](
          array,
          array2
        ).toString();
      }
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = array1.toString();
    </script>

    <div id="output " style="width:100%;"></div>
    <button onclick="callArrayUtil('reverseArray', array1)">
      Reverse Array
    </button>
    <button onclick="callArrayUtil('lastItemOfArray', array1)">
      Last Item of Array
    </button>
    <button onclick="callArrayUtil('firstItemOfArray', array1)">
      First Item of Array
    </button>
    <button onclick="callArrayUtil('concatenateArray', array1, array2)">
      Concatenate Array
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the **index.html**, a webpage showing four buttons appears. However, there is no array displayed.

expected result: four buttons and an array shown on the webpage

actual result: the array did not show on the webpage

Comment: @AndyHoffman — When the script runs, it just defines a couple of arrays and a function. It doesn't matter that `#content` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a space in your ID:

change

```
<div id = "output " style = "width:100%;">
```

to

```
<div id = "output" style = "width:100%;">
```

Answer (score 2):

After running your code, it looks like your issue is your div id:

```
<div id = "output " style = "width:100%;">
```

Your id has an extra whitespace and you are looking for:

```
document.getElementById("output")
```

It looks like you might also have some issues accessing the DOM before it has been constructed. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163060/cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null) for some more info.

Some extra tips for you:
For pretty much every major web browser available, there are web developer tools that can greatly help you debug your web apps/pages. Chrome developer tools, for example, can be accessed using `Ctrl+Shift+I` or simply right click>>Inspect.